# Bash floating points and negative values

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

Hi i am tring to produce flaoting point precision using the following code

let number1=0 number2=0 operator=+

```
printf "%0.2f\n" result=$(( number1 $operator number2 ))
```

The code works without the printf but i cannot figure out how to perform negative(-) calcs and floating points?

Comment: bash variables are integers. ksh can declare floats using the `float` alias which expands to `typeset -lE`. Better yet use `awk`, as it has natural support for floats OR if you really must have `bash` you can pipe your calcs the the `bc` (which is an external process, so expensive to do in a typical loop construct), but search here for examples. You'll get better help if you take the time to read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq. For awk help, read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not support floating point calculations, so, either you multiply the numbers being operated by as many zeros as decimals you want:

```
# 10.321 - 123.01
result=$(( 10321 - 123010 ))
echo ${result:0:-3}.${result:${#result} - 3}
```

Or simply use another tool to do this, like `bc`:

```
echo "scale=2; 10.321 - 123.01" | bc
```

Also, the syntax you've used is not valid; you should have:

```
printf "%0.2f\n" $(( number1 $operator number2 ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info however the result is required to store the sum in for interation - printf "%0.2f\n" $(( number1 $operator number2 )) wouldnt suffice

Comment: @TrickyDicky :your question doesn't state this requirement. The solution is `res=$( printf "%0.2f\n" $(( n $o n2 )) )`. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In the end i figured it out!

```
result=$(echo "scale=4; (( $number1 $operator $number2 ))" | bc)
```

Comment: result=$(echo "scale=4; $number1 $operator $number2 " | bc) <- needs no parentheses - they are superfluous because there is no order of operation -MDAS - to override.  $(( )) is a bash construct.